# on append() do something

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add some kind of an event/handler when an element is appended to the DOM...?

.click(), .change(), .keyup() etc. alike...

I need to get the height of an element as soon as it is appended and then set the height to another element

Comment: can you show your append code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event that occurs after appendChild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070865/event-that-occurs-after-appendchild)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can override the default append method and cause it to trigger a custom append event.  Then bind a handler to an element for that event: http://jsfiddle.net/H8ygx/

```
(function($) {
    var origAppend = $.fn.append;

    $.fn.append = function () {
        return origAppend.apply(this, arguments).trigger("append");
    };
})(jQuery);

$("div").bind("append", function() { alert('Hello, world!'); });

$("div").append("<span>");
```

Comment: Really never thought of overriding apend...Why isn't this just part of Jquery?  What am I missing?  Because including this seems like a no-brainer very worth while addition to jquery.

Comment: @kasdega I guess it's not included because if you append an element using another method (native JS, other libraries) the event would not be fired!

Answer (score 11):

For that you can use the "DOMSubtreeModified" event. But it has limited compatibility. See:  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/#t18

```
$('#myDiv').live("DOMSubtreeModified", function() { 
    alert('something changed inside #myDiv div');
});
```

This event handler will work with all standard DOM modifying methods: appendTo(), insertBefore(), insertAfter(), etc.

Comment: MDN says "Adding DOM mutation listeners to a document profoundly degrades the performance of further DOM modifications to that document (making them 1.5 - 7 times slower!). Moreover, removing the listeners does not reverse the damage." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer will trigger the event on the container to which you are appending, which may not be what you want. Here is a version that will trigger the event on the element(s) you are appending. Note that this still doesn't correctly handle a function input to append().

```
(function($)
{
    var jqAppend = $.fn.append;
    $.fn.append = function()
    {
        // Make a list of arguments that are jQuery objects
        var appendages = $.makeArray(arguments).filter(function(arg)
        {
            return arg instanceof $;
        });

        // Call the actual function
        var returnValue = jqAppend.apply(this, arguments);

        // Trigger "append" event on all jQuery objects that were appended
        for (var i = 0; i < appendages.length; ++i)
        {
            appendages[i].trigger('append');
        }

        return returnValue;
    };
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Scherbius.com, you can use `.on("DOMSubtreeModified")` but I suggest to apply it to the parent element (which should be known to you if you are appending to it):

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
<script>
$('<div id="child"></div>').appendTo("#parent");
//Heres what you asked about:
$("#parent).on("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){console.log("Do something!")})
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

One way is that if you are doing append yourself make a function like:

```
function do_append(elem)
{
    elem.append('......');
    // get height of your element
    // set height of another element
}
```

or tell me if this method doesn't cut it for you :)

Comment: it doesn't.. I need to know if you can attach a handler when an element is appended to the DOM

Comment: Yeah sorry, I went other way of thought :)