# jQuery UL append event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html-lists, handler

I am looking for a pretty way to handle an append/remove event from an  element, other than manually triggering an event or something of sorts.

Something like this would be amazing:

```
$('#id').on("append", function() { ... }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The accepted response is pretty interesting but I have been unable to make it work for the remove event, care to assist me on that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can trigger an `append` function with that:

```
(function($) {
    var origAppend = $.fn.append;

    $.fn.append = function () {
        return origAppend.apply(this, arguments).trigger("append");
    };
})(jQuery);

$("div").bind("append", function() { alert('Hello, world!'); });

$("div").append("<span>");
```

**This code was taken from this answer :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167210/2324107

But since remove is a little bit different because without any arguments, you will want to target the parent of the element. I modified a little bit the code before and got this result :

```
var origRemove = $.fn.remove;

$.fn.remove = function () {
    if(arguments.length){
        return origRemove.apply(this, arguments).trigger("remove");
    }else{
        var $parent = this.parent();
        console.log(this)
        origRemove.apply(this, arguments);
        $parent.trigger('remove');
        return this
    }
};
```

If there is an argument, it will trigger on the selected element. Example, `$('body').remove('div');` will trigger `remove` event on the `body`. But if you write `$('div').remove();`, it will trigger on the parent of the `div`.

I made a fiddle, take a look : http://jsfiddle.net/ZxdU3/

The event listener will be `append` and `remove`. It will not trigger is you use any other DOM insertion function (`after`, `before` or even `appendTo`).

Comment: That was an awesome response that pretty much solved my problem. Many thanks good sir!