# Does jQuery append() function fire an event after it completes?

Tags: jquery, events, append

I need to perform some action after `append()` has completed, but it doesn't appear to fire an event upon completion. Is that right or have I missed something?

If there is indeed no such event, what's the best way to detect that an append has completed?

Thanks

Comment: You can override the `append()` function to gain something like this. See a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167085/on-append-do-something

Comment: How can we tell if you're using it right if we do not have any code to go by?

Comment: Thanks ConcurrentHashMap - I'm going to take a look that.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentHashMap's comment above provides the solution I went with.

You can override the append() function to gain something like this. See a very similar question here: stackoverflow.com/questions/7167085/on-append-do-something